# Container for deletion from any place by value with fast iterations

Tags: c++, performance, stl, linked-list, containers

i'm trying to make tower defense game, i'm implementing game map for fast lookup entities in exact radius. I made it work with std::list ( for fast push_back entity pointer, and not bad deletion from any point of list), but i found that iterating through 1500 elements of list is super long. I cant hit even 10 FPS of my game. I'll show what MSVS shows in profiler:

[image: Profiler hot call stack]

after getEntitiesInRadius call next is != operator which is comparison with end of list. Next is == operator call. It runs in debug mode. But i think even for debug iterating 1500 elements is too long. Maybe i wrong with this assertion?

Comment: Iterating over list is slow. Try changing to std::vector. Deletions are slower, but push_back is (amortized) fast and iterating is fast.

Comment: I think that testing performance in Debug mode has no sense

Comment: +1 for writing a tower defense game. I love them, there can't be enough of them. :-)

Comment: @psur: Enabling debug symbols (which have virtually zero overhead) is not the same as a 'debug mode' (in which you get bounds checking and whatnot). In fact, it's pretty common to enable debug symbols and optimizations at the same time for the sake of profiling.

Comment: You could try `std::deque` which essentially is a list of vectors. It combines the low-level efficiency of the vector with the flexibility of lists.

Comment: sure i thought about deque, but i cant guarantee that entity will move exactly in stak-like way. I need random deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume your map is of a fixed size throughout the game? `std::list` is not at all a good choice if you want 'fastest', I'd start with a `vector`, and only if that doesn't suffice I'd look at other solutions.

You say you use list for 'fast push_back', but unless a vector is being resized (which can be avoided by using `reserve`, certainly on fixed size entities (as a game map would be)), push_back on a vector will be a lot faster.
Deletion might be slower (but that's not given).

On top of that, performance testing on a debug version doesn't make sense at all, first make sure there is a problem before you try to solve it!

Comment: I build it in release mode /O2 Perfomance with 1500 entities is good. Only about 4-5 percents of cpu usage. Thanks for fast answers!